# JavaScript array notation to object notation

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to access the amount value in this javascript object via object notation opposed to using array notation. How would I go about accessing the variable.

The javascript object is called: **allTargetsData**, which contains an object called **originalTarget** which branches into: Year, showroom, month as shown in the image.

[image]

The following function is used to access these objects however my object notation for the variable: monthTargetData is syntactically bugged as I'm trying to translate it from array notation.

```
function printFullReport(){
    var requestYear = $('#changeYear').val();
    var requestMonth = parseInt($('#changeMonth').val());

    var url = '/fpdf/requests/print_fullreport1.php?year=' + requestYear + '&month=' + getMonth(requestMonth);

    console.log(allTargetsData);
    //var showroomNo = 29;
    var showrooms = [1, 3, 4, 24, 27, 29, 34, 36, 37, 8, 21, 25, 26, 28, 31, 33, -1];
    for (var i = 0; i <showrooms.length; i++){

        var showroomData = allTargetsData.monthlyDetail[showrooms[i]];
        var lastYear = allTargetsData.realFigure.requestYear - 1;

        var showroomname = showroomData.showroom_name;
        var monthActualData = showroomData.total;
        var monthTargetData = allTargetsData.originalTarget.requestYear.[showrooms[i]].requestMonth.amount;
        var priorYearData = JSON.stringify(allTargetsData.realFigure[requestYear - 1][showrooms[i]]['figures'][requestMonth]);
        var priorYearToDateData = showroomData.ly_ytd;
        var yearToDateTargetData = showroomData.ytd_target;
        var yearToDateActualData = showroomData.ytd;

        var calculation1 = showroomData.ytd - showroomData.ly_ytd;
        var YTDVsPYTDSalesCurrencyData = Math.round(calculation1*10000)/100;

        var calculation2 = parseFloat(showroomData.ytd - showroomData.ly_ytd)/showroomData.ly_ytd;
        var YTDVsPYTDSalesinPercentData = Math.round(calculation2*10000)/100;

        var calculation3 = showroomData.ytd - showroomData.ytd_target;
        var YTDVsYTDTargetinSalesCurrencyData = Math.round(calculation3*100)/100;

        var calculation4 = parseFloat(showroomData.ytd - showroomData.ytd_target)/parseFloat(showroomData.ytd_target);
        var YTDVsYTDTargetinPercentData = Math.round(calculation4*10000)/100;
        console.log(showroomname);
    }
}
```

I was previously accessing it via this declaration:

```
var monthTargetData = JSON.stringify(allTargetsData.originalTarget[requestYear][showrooms[i]][requestMonth]['amount']);
```

Comment: object notation/array notation? do you mean *dot notation* vs *bracket notation* as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)?

Comment: What is the problem with `allTargetsData.originalTarget[requestYear][showrooms[i]][requestMonth]["amount"]`?

Comment: I was simply told that I'm treating allTargetsData object as an array, and I should be treating as an object instead. So was asked to change it.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes I believe so, as bracket notation is treating the object as an array. I was asked to instead asked to treat it as an object.

Comment: @helloworld the bracket notation does not treat the object as an array. It allows to access properties of an object using a variable, or allows to access properties that contain chars that would be invalid otherwise (e.g. `object['a property name with spaces']`). So `[requestMonth]['amount']` and `[requestMonth].amount` mean the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't due to the usage of variables to access the data - those can't be used with dot notation. The only thing you could change about the line is `amount`. It could be

```
allTargetsData.originalTarget[requestYear][showrooms[i]][req‌​uestMonth].amount
```

The error in your code lies here (not sure if there are more of those errors)

```
allTargetsData.originalTarget.requestYear.[showrooms[i]].requestMonth.amount;
                                        ^^^ dot and bracket notation doesn't work
```

> I believe so, as bracket notation is treating the object as an array

No it isn't, an array doesn't have (string) keys other than an index. You would never access an array element with `something['string']`

Comment: I don't see how does this help?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, which, vague as it is, it's easily misunderstood. So how does this answer the question?

Comment: *You would never access an array element with something['string']* What are you talking about? `var arr = [1,2]; arr.myProp = "myProp"; console.log(arr["myProp"])`.

Comment: I don't plan to use it like that, I'm just pointing out that some of the affirmations you make are wrong. OP had this problem (`requestYear.[showrooms[i]]`), that's it.